# Как сохранить конфиг keymap (PHPStorm)?

Tags: phpstorm

В PHPStorm имеется возможность сохранить общую тему редактора, но вот как сохранить keymap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В главном меню можно выбрать что экспортировать: File -> Export settings

[image: File -> Export settings]

Потом это можно импортировать обратно через File -> Import settings